# codenameone UI distorts on Windows phone

Tags: user-interface, codenameone

I am trying to build a UI which should work on all mobile platforms. But currently the UI is getting distorted on Windows Phone. (Displays correctly on other devices like Android, IOS..). The text boxes are places one below other but are getting overlapped on each other, truncating the bottom part of each text box.

Need to know the correct way to design the UI, so that it should display properly on all mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone target is a dead end target as Microsoft has effectively abandoned the platform. We are now focusing on the [Universal Windows Platform](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-developers-can-finally-target-windows-uwp.html) and have a [developer guide section for it here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-uwp.html).